# How to query multiple tables with a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: user, friend_recommendation, and movie.
I would like to get the name of the person who recommended this movie to me, along with the movie information from the movie table, and the comment in the friend_recommendation table. How do I do this?

Assume that user table has name as an attribute, movie table has movie title as an attribute, and friend_recommendation has UID (user who recommends), FID (who is recommended), and COMMENT (what is the comment from UID to FID)

Is it even possible to do this in one query?

Comment: i think you also need the film reference in friend_recommendation table

Comment: And the user table needs an `id` field not just `name` but apart from that just seems like you need to `JOIN` all three tables and give an appropriate `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So three tables, essentially with these fields (greatly simplified):

```
users (userId, name)
movies (movieId, movieInfo)
recommendations (fromUserId, toUserId, movieId, comment)

SELECT fromUser.name, toUser.name, m.movieInfo, r.comment
FROM recommendations r
INNER JOIN movies m ON m.movieId = r.movieId
INNER JOIN users fromUser ON r.fromUserId = fromUser.userId
INNER JOIN users toUser ON r.toUserId = toUser.userId
WHERE r.toUserId = << my user id, or whatever your criteria are >>
```

*Edit in response to the comments below:* Also retrieving the name/details of the user the movie was recommended *to* is as simple as joining to the users table again. You can see in the `JOIN`s that we select from `users` twice.

Comment: awesome..in a rate from 0-10 how complex do you think is this query?

Comment: @alexander: I'd give it a 2 out of 10... why?

Comment: what if I want the name of both the recommender and the recommended person? I think it changes the whole thing?

Comment: can someone clarify my question above?